# Changing array values to array index

Tags: arrays, compare-and-swap

I have array 
i/p: a1[]={3,2,0,1};
I want output to be: 
o/p: a1[]={2,3,1,0}

i.e the index becomes value and value becomes index. 
(condition: USE SAME ARRAY a1, no EXTRA array)

Comment: in what language you want? explain more

Comment: C Cpp Java any will do.

Comment: the answer provided, not satisfied?

Comment: Not Working, the output of the below logic is : 3 2 1 0

Comment: can u explain more please

Answer (score 1):

traveling through an array to self modifying without a temp then probably would needs some recursion. 
but considering more memory footprint on stack and all the variables in between and generally more CPU instructions it can beats you big time against a simple for-loop with a temp array :

```js
var a1 = [3,2,0,1]; // desire: [2,3,1,0]
// desire becomes surrender , surrender becomes power
r(a1);
function r(arr, index = 0) {
  if( index < arr.length )
 arr[arr[index]] = r(arr,index+1);
 // the index become value, and the value become index
 // hunter become hunted
 return index-1;
}
console.log(a1);
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir!!